# Get seperate values form the bootstrap range-slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to get the min and max value from a `bootstrap` range slider. I want both values to use in an array.

I have this `function`:

```
var slider = new Slider('#periodslider', {
     formatter: function(value) {
         var period = ['1-1/Jaar-2', '1-6/Jaar-2', '31-12/Jaar-2', '1-1/Jaar-1', '1-6/Jaar-1', '31-12/Jaar-1'];
         //return period[value - 1];
     }
});
```

What I want is to use the min value to label the value to a label within the period array. Same goes for the max value.

With a normal slider I use this `function`:

```
var slider = new Slider("#frequencyslider", {
    //tooltip: 'always',
    formatter: function(value) {
        var frequency = ['Maand', 'Kwartaal', 'Jaar'];
        return frequency[value - 1];
    }
});
```

This doesn't work for what I want becaus with a range slider it outputs the values as: `1:5`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: the docs of `bootstrap-slider.js` pointed out that in the case of a range slider, the value type isn't `float` but an `array`.

To get what I wanted, I made the function like this:

```
var slider = new Slider('#periodslider', {
 formatter: function(value) {
     var period = ['1-2013', '7-2013', '1-2014', '7-2014', '1-2015'];
     return period[value[0]] + " tot " + period[value[1]];
     }
});
```

This works perfectly!